# bat file to extract header of csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I need some help and guidance. 
I have the script below that looks for csv files in a folder. Grabs the file name and header of the file to an output file.

The scripts works, but the header is getting chopped at the end of the line in the output file. how do I pipe the entire header to the output file?

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
set "line="
set /p "line="<"%%~a"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo %%a %line%":">>output.txt
echo(!line!>> output.txt 
endlocal
)
```

Comment: I don't really get your problem... When i try working with the code it looks good. What do you mean by "the header is getting chopped at the end of the line". Can you show an example

Comment: `echo %%a %line%` --> `echo %%a !line!`

Comment: Why is your `setlocal` inside your loop?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how long your csv headers are.

In your code, you are reading the header using redirected input and `set /p`. This method allows a maximum input of 1022 characters.

You can use a `for /f` to read the files, but this is also limited to the max command line length, in this case 8192 characters.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%a in ('
        findstr /n "^" *.csv ^| findstr /b "[^:]*:1:"
    ') do (
        echo(%%a:
        echo(    %%c
    )) > output.txt
```

This code simply read input files with a `findstr` command, numerate output lines and from this output retrieve only the first line for each file. The `for /f` splits the lines using colons to retrieve the first three tokens in the lines: the file name, the line number and the line contents.

**edited** to adapt to comments

As pointed, there is a limit and the real data has collided with it.

I don't see a bulletproof pure batch solution, but a hybrid file can handle the problem

```dos
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getBatchFileReference _f0

    (
        for %%a in (*.csv) do (
            echo %%a
            <"%%a" cscript //nologo //e:Jscript "%_f0%"
        )
    ) > output.txt

    goto :eof

:getBatchFileReference returnVar
    set "%~1=%~f0"
    goto :eof

@end
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine());
```

Saved as `.cmd` or `.bat`, the file contains an initial zone with batch code and a final zone with javascript code.

For each `csv` file, the batch part will redirect it as input to the javascript part to read the first line and output it.

Comment: yes you are correct, the csv file headers are very long! I will give your script a try

Comment: findstr returned that the line is too long!

Comment: @user396123, Big files! It was a possibility, answer updated.